# Resource is not found in classpath when using maven-assembly plugin

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm using maven assembly to pack an executable jar with its dependencies and resources. The resources (spring application context) are excluded from the jar. When I run `mvn assembly:assembly`, the tests run and the build succeeds. However, when I run the executable jar after the assemby packaging I get `FileNotFoundException`. The dependencies such as spring framework that are packed under `\lib` are found. The resource `my-application-context.xml` file is also packaged under `\lib`. Can you please help?

Here is the the POM:

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>*.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.myapp.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

and the descriptor:

```
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<files>
    <file>
        <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/my-application-context.xml</source>
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
    </file>
</files>
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.build.scriptSourceDirectory}</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>*.bat</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>*.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

Comment: What does the generated manifest file in your executable jar look like?

Answer (score 1):

You might be experiencing [this obscure problem](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t365098-manifest-mf-and-index-list.html), related to the INDEX.LIST file of the dependency jars.